# Change a standard QGraphicsItem color (brush)

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyside

I implemented a custom `QGraphicsItem` (representing a car) that contains multiple `QGraphicsItem` : a text, a line, an image, ...

How can I change the other item's brush (hence : color, border thickness, ...) while still using the default drawing process (that is without implementing a custom `paint()` for each item) ?

P.S : I managed to do this with a `QGraphicsLineItem` (with the `setPen` method) but it doesn't seem to work for a text, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the `setBrush` method instead of `setPen` for `QGraphicsLineItem` and `QGraphicsPathItem`.

For `QGraphicsTextItem`, I needed to use `setDefaultColor` (and use some methods on the object's font : `myTextItem.font().setBold(True)` for instance)